# What does "ei" mean in the Google homepage url https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=xgH...?

Tags: url

I know about some of the parameters in a google url, such as:

- `gws` =google web server
- `rd` = redirected
- `cr` = country reffered

But I noticed one I cannot identify: `&ei=`. What does the `ei` mean in this URL?

```
http://www.google.co.in/url?ei=qWwlUqD4MIrRrQfD9ICIDw&...etc...
```

Comment: dulipcate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300885/meaning-for-google-homepage-parameters-gfe-rd-gws-rd-ei

Comment: Interestingly the parameter appears for `google.co.uk` only when referred from `google.com`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `ei` parameter contains a timestamp—probably with microseconds—which corresponds to the time when the search results were served.

Your particular ei value (`qWwlUqD4MIrRrQfD9ICIDw`) contains the following values:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1378184361
    [1] => 801824
    [2] => 15427722
    [3] => 4043323971
)
```

The timestamp (`1378184361`) corresponds to 03/09/2013 05.59.21.
The microseconds are 801824 (probably).

(Unfortunately no-one is going to be able to confirm whether they are microseconds or not, but the timestamp (in seconds) is obvious.)

See this [guide to decoding ei values](https://deedpolloffice.com/blog/articles/decoding-ei-parameter), which also provides an open-source PHP function.

Answer (score 7):

You must have used the wrong search terms. A quick search for: `google parameter +"ei="` turned up [this blog entry](http://web.archive.org/web/20140625145138/http://www.rankpanel.com/blog/google-search-parameters/) which says the `ei=` parameter:

> Passes on an alphanumeric parameter that decodes the originating SERP
>   where user clicked on a related search...