# Meaning for google homepage parameters (gfe_rd,gws_rd,ei)

Tags: url

When I open a google page, the URL shows as:

```
https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-IyiU-OEDe3V8gewwYBg&gws_rd=ssl
```

I would like to know, why it has those parameters and why Google adds them?

#### i.e.

`gfe_rd` `gws_rd` `ei`

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584386/what-does-ei-mean-in-the-google-homepage-url-https-www-google-co-in-gws-rd

Answer (score 14):

This webpage seems to have a good answer to that one, taken from Easy News Information, the title is "Google gfe_rd=cr&ei= URL Mystery Revealed", here's the link:

http://ramdynamo.blogspot.com.es/2014/03/google-gferdcr-url-mystery-revealed.html

The information requested above is summarised on the page as:

"Here in ?gfe_rd=cr&ei=
gfe means Google Front-End,
rd means Redirect,
cr means Country.
(till this you can find in all websites)
 And the final ei means Engine Id and also some random combination of numbers and letters is a cookie sent to our desktop.."

Hope that helps.